# How to read word doc contents into html using flask/jinja

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am a novice in web development using flask/jinja. I have content in my word file. I want to read the word file contents (text3.docs) into my html document (home.html). The home.html extends from base.html. I tried the below code but I am getting decoding error. kindly help.

**Project structure:**

[image]

**Home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <p>{{file}}</p>
{% endblock%}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href={{url_for('static', filename='images/logo1.png')}}>
    <title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    >

    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css')}}>

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light py-lg-0 " id="customNavbar">  
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <!-- Add logo -->
                <img src={{url_for('static', filename='images/logo1.png')}} alt="logo">
            </a>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggle-collapsed d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-expanded="true" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    id="togglerButton">
                    
                    <span class="line"></span> 
                    <span class="line"></span> 
                    <span class="line" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>        

            <form class="lg-flex">
                <button type="button" href="/signin"  class="btn btn-custom">Sign In</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </nav>    
    </div>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

</body>

</html>
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

f = open('Website/static/data/text3.docx', 'r', encoding="utf8")
file = f.read()

@routes.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('Home.html', file=file)
```

**main.py**

```
from Website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**style.css** (css file might not be required but still i am providing below for reference)

```
#customNavbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #4a438f;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#customNavbar .btn-custom {
    background-color: #4a438f;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #4a438f;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Word docs are not html. You can't treat them as such and just insert their file contents into an html page. You will need a conversion library

Comment: Look at the module `python-docx` https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html

Comment: If you just want the text and have a large number of documents try Apache Tika (there' a python wrapper for it). If it's a small number of documents there are python docx libraries which will allow you to access the document contents at a low level. If you can avoid putting your document in docx to begin with I'd do that. Finally, DOCX files are a collection of XML files (perhaps an oversimplification!) so you could insert for example the document.xml of your DOCX file in to your web page but I doubt that's what you want! I believe word can export as HTML - probably still not what you want :)